# UILabel not showing In-App Purchase Title

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, uilabel

I am getting my In-App Purchase **Title** (I can see it in `NSLog`), but the `UILabel` that shows the title gets called after `viewDidLoad`.  Is there any way I can get the Title before `viewDidLoad`, so that the UILabel will show the **Title**?

Below is my code.  Let me know if you need me to post anything more, thanks!

PurchaseViewController.h

```
@interface PurchaseViewController : UIViewController
<SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *product;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *productDescription;
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender;
- (void)getProductInfo:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@property (nonatomic) int buttonNumber;

@end
```

PurchaseViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate
- (void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    if (products.count !=0) {
        _product = products[0];
        //_buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    }
    else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }

}



- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The label only exists after the view did load. Not clear what your issue is from your description.

Comment: The `productTitle` and `productDescription` don't load in the `IBOutlet`s when the view loads.  I'd like the `IBOutlet`s to show the `productTitle` and `productDescription` when the view loads.  But it only cycles thru the methods after the view loads, so it leaves the `IBOutlet`s blank because nothing has been found for the `productTitle` and `productDescription` yet. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual architecture is to get the product info *before* showing the view containing the info. Then you pass that info to your view controller as you create the view controller and show its view.

Comment: So I need to get the info on the previous view controller then?

Comment: That's what I do. There's a button offering the user more info. If the user taps it, I attempt to gather the info from the store, and if I succeed, I create the next view controller, populate it, and present it.

Comment: The same is true of _any_ view controller where you want it to appear with all its information in place. You have to gather that information beforehand. That is the nature of time; it goes only in one direction!

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, you shouldn't handle these things in any view controller code. Fetching product infos and similar stuff like that (Location, Session, app's models' factories etc.) is a typical use case of shared data for a (optionally stateful) Manager singleton (f.e. PurchaseManager in this case) which would be called on app launch/AppDelegate methods and work in the background, independently on your UI code/threads.

Example:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[PurchaseManager defaultManager] fetchProducts];
}
```